# Angular ng include form action Post URL isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

Form post is not triggered if it is included in parent html using ng-include.

```
<div ng-include src="'form.html'"></div>
```

**The form.html file code as follows**

```
<form action="next/login" method ="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="login_input_field v_align_top">
                <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="email">
            </td>
            <td class="login_input_field">
                <input type="password" name="pass" ng-model="password">
            </td>
            <td class="login_button_container">
                <button type="submit" id="login" name="login">Login</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

If i do the submit in the form the URL is not navigated on the browser's URL bar. No action is performed on the submit event.

Please explain the angular logic behind the functionality.

**Its not about include the template.**

Question:

Form Submit behavior alters 
Example html page: index.html
1) I have a form inside a index.html page and submitting it alters my URL then page refreshes and get the response 
2) If i have the form in a template and include it in the index.html. URL doesn't alters and page doesn't refresh also.

What is difference between point 1 and 2?

Comment: Why "'form.html'" ? should it not be: "form.html" ? notice your ' (single quotes).

Comment: "form.html"  will act has the scope variable.
When ur binding with "'form.html'"  it will act as the string and search for the matching template name

Comment: you should probably go with <div ng-include="'form.html'"></div>

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is using `ng-include` inside div as below.

```
<div ng-include src="'form.html'"></div>
```

But for using `src` attribute of [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) use it as separate element as below.

```
<ng-include
  src="string"
  [onload="string"]
  [autoscroll="string"]>
</ng-include>
```

For using `ng-include` with div use as below:

```
<div ng-include="form.html"></div>
```

For using `ng-include` as seperate element, use code as below:

```
<ng-include src="form.html"></ng-include>
```

Comment: What is difference between 
<div ng-include src="'form.html'"></div>
and
<div ng-include="form.html"></div>

Because when i am form submitting inside the included html template. 
Url in the browser doesn't changes. Where instead of ng-include form submit if i directly giving in the html mentioned url changing?

What is secret between ng-include(inside form submit) or direct form(form submit)?

Answer (score 0):

To change your code instead of as below:

```
<div ng-include="" src="'form.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/JRgY5WkG06Og5JT3RjCG?p=preview) for this,

```
<div ng-include="'form.html'"></div>
```

works, and so does J.M.Farook's answer

```
<div ng-include="" src="'form.html'"></div>
```